# Security of Seeded PRNGs

Tags: javascript, random, cryptography

I wanted to create an application where a login password could be the seed to a pseudo random number generator to recreate an encryption key. This encryption key would then be used to encrypt all data sent to and from the application's database, making user data out of reach of even the host.

Can this use of a PRNG even be cryptographically secure? If so, what PRNG algorithms are best for this application? Is important to enforce a decent length minimum password length? Any other concerns with this setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a key derivation function such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (Password Based Key Derivation Function 2) which is designed to do exactly what you need.

You pass the password, a random seed from a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) and a repetition count. The random seed does not need to be secret and can be saved with the encrypted data. The count should be chosen such that the derivation takes about 100ms.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that the crypto tools on Node have the key derivation function you describe. I'll produce some code and post it for reference.